# How to place the logo, name, button and nav in header

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want to make this header but I stucked

I tried to place it in different ways, but nothing worked. How can I place the text near the logo and make an indent from the edge of the button?

https://codepen.io/Pero-Kairu/pen/mdXvaBV

```
    <header class="header">
        <div class="wrap_logo">
        <img class="logo" src="icons/logo.svg" alt="Logo">
        <p class="name">Travel Portal</p>
  </div>
    
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav_links">
                <li><a href="#">How It Works</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Plan Your Trip</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Destinations</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Travel Stories</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
   
    
        <form class="login_button">
            <input type="button" value="Login">
        </form>
    </header>

    li, a, button {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white; 
}

li{
    list-style-type: none;
    
}

header {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed; 
    justify-content: space-between; 
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: rgba(242, 120, 92, 0.7);
    color: white;
}

.nav_links li {
    display: inline-block; 
    margin: 0 42px; 
}
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? What does "place the text near the logo" mean? Near as in beside, on top, on the bottom...? And what does "make an indent from the edge of the button" mean? Could you provide a picture of what your goal is?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add a photo!

i am trying to do this header

https://ibb.co/6bWdPLk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this full HTML markup & CSS code. It's the perfect code for desktop devices. I hope it will help you better.

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="wrap_logo">
        <a href="index.html">
            <img class="logo" src="https://icon-library.com/images/avatar-png-icon/avatar-png-icon-13.jpg" alt="Logo">
            <span class="name">Travel Portal</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <nav>
        <ul class="nav_links">
            <li><a href="#">How It Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Plan Your Trip</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Destinations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Travel Stories</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <form action="#" class="login_button">
        <input type="button" value="Login">
    </form>
</header>

.header {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between; 
  background-color: rgba(242, 120, 92, 0.7);
}

.header .wrap_logo > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.header .wrap_logo img {
  max-width: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.header .nav_links {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header .nav_links > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.header .nav_links > li:not(:last-child) {
  margin: 0 42px 0 0;
}
.header .nav_links > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

Let me know if you need any other help.
Thank You.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed. Couls you please explain why we should use z-index: 999 in header here and could you tell me about construction > li > a? How we can describe it? I want to find more info about it. Thank you in advance! с:

Answer (score 0):

All you are missing is some styling in your `.wrap_logo` class:

```css
.wrap_logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Also if you want to have some space between the elements and the borders of the page you can just add some padding.

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```html
.logo{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 15px;
  
}
.name{
  posirion: absolute;
  margin-left: 70px;
}
```

Comment: `position-absolute` is not a good practice in this situation. Absolute positioning removes the elements from the flow of the document and can cause issues on responsive.

Comment: @HelenaSánchez yes I understand but I wanted to help. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: This is not common practice. You answer could be enhanced by showing some more code. In some circumstances absolute positioning is totally the right thing to do however.
In a navigaiton flexbox or grid are the safer way to position elements however.

Comment: @Frizzant Of course I agree with you